# How can I group ids by frequency and then exposure type

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to create a frequency table where I can see the number of times an app has been opened after it has been exposed to something (first_impression).

I also want this grouped by exposure type. When I add the CASE statement around exposure, my number of launches turns to one, why is that happening?
I think I'm making a mistake with the grouping?

```
; DROP TABLE IF EXISTS launches_post_exposure

; CREATE TEMP TABLE launches_post_exposure (
          ID VARCHAR(36), app_launches INTEGER, launches_category VARCHAR(50) , exposure VARCHAR(50)  )
          
;INSERT INTO launches_post_exposure (id, app_launches, launches_category, exposure)

SELECT
    DISTINCT la.id AS id
    , la.app_launches
    , CASE 
        WHEN la.app_launches = 1 THEN '1'
        WHEN la.app_launches = 2 THEN '2'
        WHEN la.app_launches = 3 THEN '3'
        WHEN la.app_launches = 4 THEN '4'
        WHEN la.app_launches = 5 THEN '5'
        WHEN la.app_launches = 6 THEN '6'
        WHEN la.app_launches = 7 THEN '7'
        WHEN la.app_launches = 8 THEN '8'
        WHEN la.app_launches = 9 THEN '9'
        WHEN la.app_launches >= 10 THEN '>=10'
     END AS launches_category
     , exposure
     
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      distinct op.id as id
      , COUNT(op.open_date) as app_launches
      , **CASE 
        WHEN op.open_date > ex.first_impression THEN 'post_exposure'
        WHEN op.open_date < ex.first_impression THEN 'pre_exposure'
        WHEN ex.first_impression IS NULL THEN 'Unexposed' 
         END as exposure**
    FROM 
      opened op
      LEFT JOIN exposed ex
      ON op.id = ex.id
      GROUP BY op.id, op.open_date, ex.first_impression
    ) la
    GROUP BY la.id, la.app_launches, la.exposure;
    
SELECT 
  COUNT(DISTINCT id),
  launches_category ,
  exposure
  
FROM 
launches_post_exposure
GROUP BY  launches_category
ORDER BY launches_category
```

Comment: The `;` should go at the **end** of a statement, not the beginning

Comment: "I also want this grouped by exposure type" then use  the expression `CASE 
        WHEN op.open_date > ex.first_impression THEN 'post_exposure'
        WHEN op.open_date < ex.first_impression THEN 'pre_exposure'
        WHEN ex.first_impression IS NULL THEN 'Unexposed' 
         END` instead of `ex.first_impression`

Comment: can you show input and output tables?